# How to calculate the efficiency of Simplex algorithm for diet

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, simplex

I'm trying to write a program to solve diet problem http://www.phpsimplex.com/en/diet_problem.htm

using SIMPLEX algorithms. My assignment require also to calculate the efficiency of the algorithms.

I understood from wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm that it's has exponential time in worst case. But it doesn't  show the exact big O notation, or how I could calculate that.

Is there any advice how could I calculate the efficiency of Simplex algorithm for the above diet problem?

Comment: Are you looking for average run time? What do you mean by "exact Big O notation"?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiency?" Run-time complexity (which is what's normally measured using big-O) requires a class of problems measured by input size, and asking for the complexity of a solution to a single problem makes no sense.